# Waiting for multiple async request

Tags: c#, asynchronous, architecture, .net-3.5, nonblocking

I'm currently working on an application sending TCP requests to a server.
My problem is only on client side. Responses are handled via some delegates to keep things asynchronous.
Here is a signature of one request method :

```
public void RequestOne(Object data, MyCallback callback)
```

But now I'm dealing with a delegate dictionary (resquest,delegate) to keep track of requests supposed to update the client state.

I don't think it's the right way to do it. I'm looking for a better architecture.

Any ideas / pattern ?

Comment: Start here: [Task Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: To expand @Jamiec You need `await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2,...);`

Comment: A good answer here will also depend on what version of .NET you're using. Can you update the tags or the question with that info.